# PHP : ignore certain number

Tags: php, html

Data using PHP , pulled from SQL Database

```
 DATA: 303030303130
```

Display into website

```
<td><?php echo $min["data"]; ?></td>
```

as `303030303130`

What im trying to display :

```
000010
```

Trying to use

```
substr(string,start,length)
```

How did i ignore number `3` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove `3` from the data string then `str_replace('3', '', $data)` would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

`<td><?php echo str_replace("3","",$min["data"]); ?></td>`

Comment: Thank for your quick help